# How do I create a Shortcut with a folder in the Start Menu on Windows

Tags: winapi, mfc

So far, I can create a Shortcut in the Start Menu, this is the result:

[image: image1]

I want to create this Shortcut with a folder, and this folder is in the Start Menu, just like this:

[image: image2]

What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
void CreateShort(CString strApp, char* pcLnk) 
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IShellLink *pisl;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (void**)&pisl);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IPersistFile* pIPF;
            pisl->SetPath(strApp);          
            hr = pisl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&pIPF);

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                USES_CONVERSION;
                LPCOLESTR lpOlestr = A2COLE(pcLnk);
                hr = pIPF->Save(lpOlestr, FALSE);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
                    AfxMessageBox(dw);
                }
                pIPF->Release();
            }
            pisl->Release();
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

**UPDATE**: I added this code when calling my function:

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL, szStartPath, CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS, 0); 
CString path = CString(szStartPath);
SHCreateDirectory(NULL,path)
strcat_s(szStartPath, MAX_PATH, "\\myapp\\");
strcat_s(szStartPath, MAX_PATH, m_acAppName);
CreateShort(m_strSetupDir, szStartPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a regular sub-folder on the filesystem underneath the Start Menu’s “Programs” group folder (which you can locate by using `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_[COMMON_]PROGRAMS)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_[Common]Programs)`), and then you can create your file shortcuts inside of your sub-folder.

Comment: I have used SHCreateDirectory() this function to create the sub-folder,and this folder created successfully in the path.However it doesn't show up in the Start Menu.I can confirm that the path is correct.Do you know why it's like this？

Comment: @Ignorant_QCY try using `CSIDL_[COMMON_]PROGRAMS`/`FOLDERID_[Common]Programs` instead

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. This is the first time I use this. The code format is always wrong when submitting.

Comment: @Ignorant_QCY you are appending `”\\myapp\\”` to `szStartPath` AFTER calling `SHCreateDirectory()`. You need to append it BEFORE instead. Also, there is no need for the `CString path` variable at all, pass `szStartPath` directly to `SHCreateDirectory()` instead. Also, consider using [`PathCombine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinea) or related function instead of using `strcat_s()`